# create a @State var area, that is based on two @State var width, an @State var height

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

How do you combine multiple state variables to form another?

I want to change the value of height OR width by some user interaction, and have everything in the view update accordingly. So the height OR width would change, and the area would change.

I imagine it would look something like this

```
@State var width: CGFloat = 50.0
@State var height: CGFloat = 100.0


@State var area: CGFloat // somehow equal to width*height
```

current solution is just calling a func

```
func area() -> CGFloat {
  width * height
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't make `area` `@State`; just make it a computed variable:

```
@State var height: CGFloat = 50.0
@State var width: CGFloat = 100.0
var area: CGFloat {
    width * height
}
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Width: \(width)")
        Text("Height: \(height)")
        Text("Area \(area)")
        Button(action: {
            self.height *= 2
        }) {
            Text("Double height")
        }
        Button(action: {
            self.width += 10
        }) {
            Text("Add 10 to width")
        }
    }
}
```

I added some code to illustrate that if `width` or `height` changes, `area` will change too, because `width` or `height` changing cause the view to be redrawn since they are `@State`. Since `area` is computed, when the view is redrawn, `area` is determined to be the product of the updated `width` and `height` values. Doing it as a function like you said in your current solution should also work, though.

If you want `area` to be `@State` so that you can pass it to other views as a `Binding`, do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var height: CGFloat = 50.0
@State var width: CGFloat = 100.0
var area: Binding<CGFloat> {
    Binding(get: {
        self.height * self.width
    }) { (newVal) in

    }
}
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Width: \(width)")
        Text("Height: \(height)")
        Text("Area \(area.wrappedValue)")
        BindingView(num: area)
        BindingView(num: $height)
        Button(action: {
            self.height *= 2
        }) {
            Text("Double height")
        }
        Button(action: {
            self.width += 10
        }) {
            Text("Add 10 to width")
        }
    }
}

struct BindingView: View {
    @Binding var num: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        Text("Binding number: \(num)")
    }
}
```

I created `BindingView` as an example of how to use bindings in different ways. For `@State` variables, you effectively turn them into a `Binding` by adding the `$` prefix, but since area is explicitly `Binding`, you do not need the `$`. Also to access the value inside the `Binding`, you just do the variable `.wrappedValue`.

Comment: OH. so the computed variable `area` will change dynamically depending on the state variables?? also yes this binding example is very helpful because I deff need to pass it to children in this situation

Comment: Yeah, the value of computed variables are only determined when they are accessed (they basically only have a getter), and since the width and height are State variables, whenever they change, the view is redrawn, which causes whatever using the area variable to "get" its computed value, which uses the new values for the width and height. And I agree, understanding how to use Bindings without State, Binding, etc. is very useful.

Comment: right right which is why you can do all that fun computed variable stuff with get and set... ok. and yes so far i have only done the passic pattern of state variable, and pass as binding to children view

Comment: No problem! And to correct something I said earlier, computed properties can have a setter, but only the getter is required; setters are optional.